# How to add Text before my Custom Term and hide it when empty

Tags: php, custom-taxonomy, tags, conditional-tags, template-tags

This is my code:

```
    <?php
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'this_is_custom' );
    $links = [];
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $term_link = get_term_link( $term, 'this_is_custom' );
        if( !is_wp_error( $term_link ) ) {
            $links[] = '<a href="' . $term_link . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';
        }
    }
    echo implode(',&nbsp;', $links);
    ?>
```

**The result are:**

```
Mango, Orange, Banana
```

**What it wants to achieve is:**

```
Tag: Mango, Orange, Banana
```

How can I display the word "Tag: " and hide it when there is no Term inside current post?

Sorry for my English. I hope you understand.
Thanks for your answer, I really appreciated.

Comment: I think you can just use `the_tags();` to show tags and it will show "Tags: Mango, Orange, Banana".

Comment: OR, you can use this to custom your text. `the_tags( 'Tags: ', ', ' );` and yes, when the there is no tag in your post, there will be nothing. no "Tags:" text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you just need to check if the `$links` variable is not empty and if so, then echo the text `Tag:`  and the `$links` (i.e. the terms list):

```php
if ( ! empty( $links ) ) {
    echo 'Tags: ' . implode( ',&nbsp;', $links );
}
```

Or a better version, check if the `$terms` is not a `WP_Error` instance and `$terms` is not empty:

```php
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'this_is_custom' );
if ( ! is_wp_error( $terms ) && ! empty( $terms ) ) {
    $links = [];
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        // ... your code.
    }
    echo 'Tags: ' . implode( ',&nbsp;', $links );
}
```

However, if all you need is to display the terms (in the **custom taxonomy** `this_is_custom`) in the form of `Tags: <tag with link>, <tag with link>, ...`, i.e. simple clickable links, then you could simply use [`the_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_terms/):

```php
// Replace your entire code with just:
the_terms( $post->ID, 'this_is_custom', 'Tags: ', ',&nbsp;' ); // but I would use ', ' instead of ',&nbsp;'
```

Comment: It's work. Thanks for make my life easier 